# Choosing a journal to offer services for review

Tags: peer-review, career-path

I'm a Master's level statistician working in academics research, public health policy, and so on. The area itself is marginally interesting to me. I'm interested in professional development, but my connections and resources are somewhat sparse. One thought I had was to offer services to provide methodologic review for scholarly journals that publish articles with data analyses. I've heard repeatedly from other academics that the need for methods review is very high, but I haven't been proactive in searching out such journals. How do you suggest I approach the matter? Do I email the editors with my CV and explain my interest?

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that some journals only allow PhD holders to review.

Comment: @TheFireGuy: That's interesting: can you give a specific example?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark sure. When I was a PhD student, I contacted the editor of "Engineering Structures" - an Elsevier journal and sent him my credentials. He replied back to me saying "Let us know when you complete your PhD." So, when I did graduate, I emailed him again and got accepted. I still have his email to this day :)